# Can not find lib Qt but it exist in the path

Tags: linux, qt, raspberry-pi, hyper-v

I have some problems with my Qt project on Hyper-V virtual linux machine. I have one lib file and header for this lib. I connected this 2 files to my .pro file but when I want to compile this project I get the error "cannot find -lftd2xx".
Her is my lines from code for file connection in .pro file:

```
win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/./ -lftd2xx
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/./ -lftd2xxd
else:unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/./ -lftd2xx

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/.
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/.
```

This two files are present in the path that is given. I also note that compilation takes place under raspberry pi and synchronization has been already performed as in the example from the qt documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the problem was. it considered in the fact that I used a library for Windows, but it was necessary for Linux